# C# MVC with Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, model-view-controller

How can I create a project in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 from C# MVC with Angular? I have seen tutorials but I see that a template appears in the videos, but it does not appear to me. help plsss

[The template is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzXEB.png)

[Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leZ0w.png)

Install multiple versions of visual studio and none have angular template

Comment: Angular is a client side technology, that gets all the data from the API server and displays the output accordingly. MVC is a server side technology that renders the data and sends it to the client. Definetly a not so precise (or even wrong ) answer, but the comments section is to short for that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CLI  command `dotnet new angular -o my-new-app`
or the GUI with visual studio 2022 v17.7 with .NET6 the option is there [image: image of how to create angular project]

try using this tutorial on the microsoft site `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio`

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are not looking for tutorials, but I had the same question and couldn't find a template as well. Hopefully this will help others looking to solve the same issue.
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/21/build-basic-web-app-with-mvc-angular

'You will be using .NET Framework 4.7.1, and you should have the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 installed. Also, you should have Node and npm installed since you will use Angular tools that require Node and npm.'